Nextjs 404 appears on all assets (js, css) after output export
For example
<script src="/_next/static/chunks/webpack-12345.js" async=""></script>

If changed to
<script src="_next/static/chunks/webpack-12345.js" async=""></script> // i have remove the "/" at start

Then there is no 404 about assets (css, js, etc...). Although the route has no effect at all, for example, the page not found still when I click on Link to "about". So nextjs mistakenly added "/" to the beginning of all assets links.
I haven't changed any settings in this regard.
I didn’t write very complicated settings, I tried not to change any settings, but the above situation still occurs, how can I solve it?
